# PHP file_put_contents save from php file

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I'm trying to get the Html source code from a php file and put it into an Html file using this:

```
file_put_contents('result.html', file_get_contents('index.php'));
```

After running this function, The "result.html" will contain the same PHP codes in the original "index.php" file, While I need "result.html" file to get the Html code after index.php has executed.
Any Help Please?. Thanks.

Comment: You will want to serve the file over HTTP to get what the browser would see, or execute the PHP in the file some other way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another way (doesn't need an http server nor access to shell):

```
<?php

ob_start();
include('index.php');
$page = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

file_put_contents('result.html', $page);

?>
```

Comment: Thanks, It actually solved two issues in my script :) Best answer +1

Answer (score 6):

You are simply copying php code into html file.

to get html source code you need to interpret php file

one way of doing this is:

```
file_put_contents('result.html', file_get_contents('http://localhost/path/to/index.php'));
```

Comment: When I put the whole URL it won't write anything inside the result.html file!. Still 0kb. Any Help?

Comment: set/check `allow_url_fopen = On` in php.ini

Answer (score 2):

Use this code

```
file_put_contents('result.html', file_get_contents('http://localhost/yourproject/index.php'));
```

Comment: When I put the whole URL it wont write anything inside the result.html file!. Still 0kb. Any Help?

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
file_put_contents('result.html', shell_exec('php path/to/index.php'));
```