# file_put_contents function not adding "echo" from php file

Tags: php, file

i'm trying to copy php file from server to html file in other path in server.
the php file contains "echo $var" and after it copy it's dosen't copy the "echo" only the html.

Example :

```
$file = file_get_contents("../view_details.php");
file_put_contents($full_date, $file);
```

the view_details.php file :

```
echo "hello world";
```

will return in html

```
echo "hello world";
```

in the page source and not hello world itself..

Comment: That's because the PHP at http://www.test.view_details.php will be executed and the result output returned to your script, this won't return  the PHP source code from the remore URL

Comment: how can i include the "echo" in the generated file ?

Comment: @nim You do know there is supposed to be a / between the top level domain and the filename? I understand that it's a fake link but you made two fundamental errors on the link, so just wanted to check.

Comment: Well if the file is on the same server, then use a filesystem reference rather than a URL, then you'll be reading the raw file and not executing it

Comment: i know and i tried using reference rather than url not working also

Comment: @nim It is not possible to have php code in html when you are executing that php file. It will be transferred to html.

Comment: If it didn't work when you used a reference other than the URL, then you probably used the wrong reference.... what is the full path to that file on your server?

Comment: @naf4me why it's not possible ?

Comment: @nim when file_get_content() pull view_details.php then its interpret as it is php code. So to resolve it you may use copy() function. Manual is: http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php

Comment: did u checked it ?
i tried also copy() function it's gives the same result as file_get_content()

Comment: found a solution :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22215465/php-file-put-contents-save-from-php-file?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

If you are including a php file and want it to execute why not use `include()`?

Answer (score -1):

instead of this $`file = file_get_contents("http://www.test.view_details.php");` try using this `$file = file_get_contents("view_details.php");`

Comment: The OP mentions that the file is from a different server path and not from the same server.

Comment: @jqheart As I read it, it's on the same server but different folder perhaps.

Comment: also when i use file_get_contents("view_details.php") i get the same result

Comment: @jqheart if the OP wants to call the file on the other folder, why not use "./"?

Comment: @nim why not use file_get_contents("./view_details.php") if it's in the other folder

Comment: @Andreas yeah looks like the files are on the same server based on nim's comment. I overlooked it friends